# Open workbook via filepath within a cell

Tags: excel, vba

Workbook x is open.

I want to:

- Open Excel workbook y (the filepath is in cell "B2" of the macro tab of workbook x).
- Copy A3:A26 from macro tab of workbook x, and paste into M41:M63 in the summary tab of workbook y.

The problem is with the B2 filepath name. I think I need to specify to pull the text from B2 to open the correct workbook.

The error message is

> Sorry, we couldn't find B2.xlsx

```vb
Sub Foo()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set y = Workbooks.Open("B2")

x.Sheets("Macro").Range("A3:A26").Copy

y.Sheets("Summary").Range("M41:M63").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following ... assumes the Sheet in Workbook `x` is actually called "Macro" (you also have a Sheet in Workbook `y` with the same name?) ... you also need to set the value for `x` which this does:

```
Sub Foo()
    Dim x As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Set x = ActiveWorkbook
    Set y = Workbooks.Open(x.Sheets("Macro").Range("B2"))
    x.Sheets("Macro").Range("A3:A26").Copy
    y.Sheets("Summary").Range("M41:M63").PasteSpecial
End Sub
```